# responsive filemanager session Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, responsive

I have successed integrated Responsive Filemanager http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/#sthash.AiTlkP17.dpbs with Codeigniter. But, if I access the button url on another browser, i can opened the filemanager (without login).

Can you help me, what can i do to protect my Responsive Filemanager with login session Codeigniter...?

if you have a link that explains the steps, please include here.

I've read the documentation to add "akey" to the url. but still accessible through other browsers without having to login.

Comment: Responsive filemanager operates *outside* of Codeigniter thus you need to do something like I explained in my answer here (some points different but logic remains the same): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607255/codeigniter-3-x-ion-auth-ckfinder-how-to-pass-the-logged-in-status-from-ion/47611881#47611881 if you want to use the session to see if accessing it is permitted (e.g. the user is logged in with session data).

Comment: thanks,, i will try it..

Answer (score 1):

I think that You have read this concept properly then

```
I've read the documentation to add "akey" to the url. but still accessible through other browsers without having to login.
```

What else I can suggest is, don't allow to access the page where responsive file manager works, to elaborate, don't allow to hit the ***URL***,untill and unless your session has values. The same scenario where user cannot access dashboard until and unless user is not logged in, by this it can be more secured, rather than generating key into url.

Also Please provide some code so that we can look on it.