# How to use codeigniter login session on tinymce editor image manager?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, tinymce

How to check CodeIgniter user auth session on `TinyMCE editor` on `image.php` file ?

Therefore, I have vulnerability with this issues. hacker can upload any file here.

Comment: Plz Post your question with code context.

Comment: Simply load the editor on authenticating the user

Comment: @Penguine are you joke with me ? this is pure vulnerability in tinyMCE editor

Comment: Check my answer here and just apply the same logic:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607255/codeigniter-3-x-ion-auth-ckfinder-how-to-pass-the-logged-in-status-from-ion?noredirect=1&lq=1 ... I'm also unfamiliar with tinymce but the way to access CI from an external app is the same. That being said, doesn't tinymce have a way where you can just access a certain page to upload an image rather than a "core" php file? Then you can just make your own controller and use CI's upload library

Comment: @TuranZamanlı If my answer was helpful mark it as green.thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a login page with `PHP` and connect it with the database. CodeIgniter `session` only works in main `CodeIgniter` `URL`. `CodeIgniter` `session` does not work out of CodeIgniter.